# Unable to import mysql-python connector Py3.8, MySQL8.0.19

Tags: python, mysql, connector

I'm running Python 3.8 and MySQL 8.0.19 and installed the mysql-connector-python-8.0.19 on Mac 10.15.4. I didn't get any errors on the installation of any of them. I can create a database through MySQL but when I try to import the connector, I get this error:

import mysql.connector
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import mysql.connector
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/**init**.py", line 41, in 
    import dns.resolver

Jaclyn Horton

Comment: In my case it turns out it was missing some prerequisites, one is dnspython and the other is protobuf. Using pip to install these corrected the problem.

pip install dnspython

pip install protobuf

Jaclyn Horton

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling it and reinstalling it again and importing it.
Run the following code on your IDLE Shell:

```
>>> import os
>>>
>>> os.system('pip uninstall mysql.connector & pip install mysql.connector')
>>>
>>> import mysql.connector as msc
>>>
>>> con_obj = msc.Connect(host='<host_name>', user='<user_name>',
password='<your_password>', autocommit=True)
```

If you don't encounter an error, you are all good!

## And one more thing,

If you don't remember any of these parameters (kwargs), and you have a default installation of MySQL, then, try:

```
>>> con_obj = msc.Connect(host='localhost', user='root',
password='tiger', autocommit=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=98225) in `mysql.connector`.  The workaround is to manually install `dnspython` using `pip` or your OS's package manager.

For example:

```
python3.8 -m pip install dnspython
```